# Get Page URL on 404 IIS Redirection (Custom Error Page in Classic ASP)

Tags: iis, asp-classic, http-status-code-404

I have implemented IIS Redirection on 404 error code and created a Custom Error Page for it. My Custom error page is written in classic asp (e.g: FileNotFound.asp). I need to write the URL of calling page (which does not exists) in my Custom Error Page.

Answer (score -1):

You need the following:

```
Request.ServerVariables (server_variable)
```

Replace it with:

```
Request.ServerVariables (HTTP_REFERER)
```

That should work.  Article on it at w3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp